# Singleton with thread initialization

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, android-asynctask, singleton

I want to make a singleton connection that starts with a asynctask. How can I getInstance and know when it finishes the connection (connected or timeout).
This is the async whith a callback interface, the singleton class needs to execute this and store the connection.

Came over [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom), don't really know what to do.

```
public class ConnectAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, Connection> {

    private ConnectionCallback callback;
    private Connection connection;

    public ConnectAsync(ConnectionCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Connection doInBackground(String... params) {

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(params[0]);
        factory.setUsername(params[1]);
        factory.setPassword(params[2]);
        factory.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
        //factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
        //factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(5000);

        try {
            connection = factory.newConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogUtil.e("Connection", null, "Connection timeout");
            return null;
        } 
        return connection;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Connection result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (callback != null)
            callback.onConnect(result);

    }

    public interface ConnectionCallback {
        public void onConnect(Connection result);
    }

}
```

From Service

```
deviceWorker.connect(new ConnectionCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConnect(Connection result) {
                        if (result != null && result.isOpen()) {
                            LogUtil.hecsLog(TAG, "DeviceWokers fully operational");
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: I do not get this completely: Do you want to "lazy" start? That means you want to start connecting when the Instance of the singleton is requested? If so: do you want the requester to block while waiting for the connection?

Comment: Yes, lazy and thread safe ! I keep getting multiple connections when I start a service.

Comment: Can you add the part where you start the service? Is it an IntentService?

Comment: Sticky service, I always need it. And I need to handle connectivity loss/gain or switch network provider. The android broadcast receiver for internet connectivity sends a lot of broadcasts when detecting provider change, I tried to return if the worker is not null but it does nothing -> it's threaded

Comment: maybe create one static ConnectAsync in your Singleton and when calling getInstance().connect() first check that this class is initialized and running (AsyncTask.getStatus()). if running then don't start another one

Comment: Hm, at first glance, I'd suggest another layer of abstraction: Make the Service provide the functions you are performing on the connection. This will hide all the connection stuff into the service. My feeling is, that this setup will be easier to maintain (and write in the first place). This way you can include "retry" functionality hidden to the service's client.

Comment: @snachmsm I will try that, Fildor I'll think about it, my project came without a design so I have to do some agile programming.

Comment: The service will have 2 connections, each one being a singleton, one for my publishing and one for consuming. It's rabbitMQ and they suggest one connection per worker.